# How to use GUI In Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, gui, vnc

I have installed GNOME GUI in my Ubuntu server (Digital Ocean). Now I need to access the GUI. I use putty to connect but Putty Is only used as a terminal (SSH) there are no GUI options on it. so I thought I will use Teamviewer to access GUI.

As I told before, I don't have any option or service to directly start and use TeamViewer.(There is no KVM or console)
so I used this commands to install Teamviewer via terminal.

```
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_amd64.deb
```

And installed Teamviewer

Now I need to open TeamViewer via terminal and print user id and password of Teamviewer in the terminal so that I can connect

Alternately, You can suggest any other options to connect to the desktop (GUI).
I tried VNC and XRDP, both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I did not tried this but you can try to use SSH X or Y to run TeamViewer via X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -X user@host teamviewer
```

or

```
ssh -Y user@host teamviewer
```